# Passing a List in Json Function

Tags: python, list, function

I have been struggling with the correct solution to manipulating the string I am getting from a parsed Json object.

I want to create a list of words to exclude from the string.  I have titled this list as 'ignore' below.  I dont get an error but it doesn't really do what I want.

Below is my code:

```
def extract_info(msg):
    created_time = msg['created_time'].replace('T', ' ').replace('+0000', '')
    ignore = ["you","all","has","can","that", "the"]
    message = msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.').replace('\n', '').replace(',', '').encode('utf8') 
    for ignore in message:
        if ignore in message:
            message = message.replace(ignore, '')
    user_id = msg['from']['id']
    return (created_time, message, user_id)



def main():
    ts = FacebookSearch()
    data = ts.search('dishwasher')
    js = json.loads(data)
    messages = (extract_info(msg) for msg in js.get('data', []))
    write_csv('fb_dishwasher.csv', messages, append=True)
```

The Problem with the above code is that it doesn't write anything to the .csv file it creates.  It is just a blank field.

I want to any words from the 'ignore' list with blank spaces in 'message' but now all I have is blank space:<

I don't understand why it is blank.  Also since there is no error that is when I get kinda stuck.  I would really appreciate any suggestions or help with what I have missed here.

Comment: It doesn't print anything? There isn't a single print statement there.

Comment: the .csv file it writes has the message field as a blank

Comment: Use the `print` function. print every single thing you have to check their values.

Comment: I did that and it is just blank.  If I remove "for ignore in message:
        if ignore in message:
            message = message.replace(ignore, '')" it works but then my ignore list isnt being passed through the 'mesage' text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `ignore` as a list and then try to re-use it in a for loop which probably messes up everything. Further, you don't want to iterate a string! 
Try instead to do:

```
ignore = ["you","all","has","can","that", "the"]
    message = msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.').replace('\n', '').replace(',', '').encode('utf8') 
    for word in message.split():
        if word in ignore:
            message = message.replace(word, '')
```